# Accept xml message in java from server

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

I am a newbie in using web services so sorry for the simple question. I want to receive a xml message or file from the server in java and then parse it and wanted help.

Answer (score 1):

Read content and save as file:

```
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/abc.xml");
Path xml = Paths.get("/path/to/abc.xml");;
try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
  Files.copy(in, xml);
}
```

Read content and parse as XML:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/abc.xml");
try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
  Document d = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
  ...
}
```

These solutions use built-in classes provided by Java:

- [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)
- [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)
- [`org.w3c.dom.Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)

Comment: Where do URL, Path and Document come from?

Comment: @Amadán they are built-in classes provided by Java. I updated the answer